# PHP extension works from browser not from CMD

Tags: php, doctrine, continuous-integration, command-line-interface

I'm still struggling integrate APC with EasyPHP for testing Doctrine + CI.

- Installed APC
- configured php.ini
- see it in phpinfo()

Added this to my php.ini :

```
[APC]
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.enable_cli=1
```

created a test file test.php :

```
<?php
 print_r(apc_sma_info());
?>
```

**accessing with browser (getting result on screen) :**
Array ( [num_seg] => 1 [seg_size] => 33554368 [avail_mem] => 33237360 [block_lists] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [size] => 33237336 [offset] => 317048 ) ) ) )

**running from command prompt** : D:\devl\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www>php test.php

Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_sma_info() in D:\devl\EasyPHP-5.3.5.
0\www\test.php on line 2

any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know EasyPHP - but there are often different php.ini files for Apache and Cli...

Please check this first for your WAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

apache and CLI may have different php.ini files, so check which is the loaded php.ini in the cli environment.